# MySQLdb Connecting To Database Error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to connect to my SQL database on pythonanywhere and to connect I'm running this.

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect("MYUSERNAME.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com","MYUSERNAME","DBPASSWORD","DBTABLENAME")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT * from game_db")

rows = c.fetchall()

for eachrow in rows:
    print(eachrow)
```

I'm doing this from my laptop and I get this error when trying to connect.

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on MYUSERNAME.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (10060)")
```

Is there some sort of authentication I need to do or is there some other problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the pythonanywhere mysql service isn't accessible from outside pythonanywhere (unless you have a paid account, in which case you can use an ssh tunnel: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/)